# Solver stops before obtaining a solution in the MATLAB optimization toolbox

Tags: matlab, optimization, linear-programming, solver

I use ***fmincon*** function of MATLAB optimization toolbox for a minimization problem. The basic part of the code is as follows:

```
clc;
clear;
load('coord_points.mat');
load('coord_centroids.mat');
numberOfPoints=200;
numberOfCentroids=40;
Q=5;
tau=0.1;

d = zeros(numberOfPoints,numberOfCentroids);

for j=1:numberOfCentroids
    centroid = coord_centroids(j,:);
    for i=1:numberOfPoints
        point = coord_points(i,:);
        d(i,j)=norm(centroid-point);
    end
end

sectorization = optimproblem;
x = optimvar('x',numberOfPoints,numberOfCentroids,'LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',1);
y = optimvar('y',1,'LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',1);

qjExpression=optimexpr(numberOfCentroids);

for j=1:numberOfCentroids
    qjExpression(j) = sum(x(:,j));
end

qExpression = mean(qjExpression);

objExpression = y; 

%%%
sectorization.Objective = objExpression;

cons1 = optimconstr(numberOfPoints,1);
for i=1:numberOfPoints
    cons1(i) = sum(x(i,:)) == 1;
end

cons2 = optimconstr(numberOfCentroids,1);
for j=1:numberOfCentroids
    cons2(j) = sum(x(:,j)) >= 1;
end

cons3 = optimconstr(numberOfCentroids,1);
for j=1:numberOfCentroids
    cons3(j) = sum(x(:,j)) <= Q*(1+tau);
end

cons4 = optimconstr(1);
varianceOfQj = optimexpr(1);
for j=1:numberOfCentroids
    varianceOfQj = varianceOfQj + (qjExpression(j)-qExpression)^2;
end
varianceOfQj=varianceOfQj/numberOfCentroids;
cons4 = varianceOfQj - y <= 0;

sectorization.Constraints.cons1=cons1;
sectorization.Constraints.cons2=cons2;
sectorization.Constraints.cons3=cons3;
sectorization.Constraints.cons4=cons4;
%load('sol.mat');
sol.x=zeros(numberOfPoints,numberOfCentroids);
sol.y=1;
problem = prob2struct(sectorization,sol);

options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'MaxFunctionEvaluations',5000,'Algorithm','active-set','Display','iter')
[x,fval] = fmincon(problem);
```

But I get the following result:

*Solver stopped prematurely.*

*fmincon stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit, options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 3.000000e+03.*

However, as seen in the code, in the options section, ***max function evaluations*** is made equal to 5000.

Even, while the program is running, at first outputs as follows are appeared:

```
*options = 

  fmincon options:

   Options used by current Algorithm ('active-set'):

   (Other available algorithms: 'interior-point', 'sqp', 'sqp-legacy', 'trust-region-reflective')
   Set properties:

                    Algorithm: 'active-set'

                      Display: 'iter'

       MaxFunctionEvaluations: 5000

   Default properties:

               CheckGradients: 0

          ConstraintTolerance: 1.0000e-06

     FiniteDifferenceStepSize: 'sqrt(eps)'

         FiniteDifferenceType: 'forward'

            FunctionTolerance: 1.0000e-06

                MaxIterations: 400

          OptimalityTolerance: 1.0000e-06

                    OutputFcn: []

                      PlotFcn: []

    SpecifyConstraintGradient: 0

     SpecifyObjectiveGradient: 0

                StepTolerance: 1.0000e-06

                     TypicalX: 'ones(numberOfVariables,1)'

                  UseParallel: 0

   Show options not used by current Algorithm ('active-set')*
```

What can I do to make the Solver work properly? Why does it stop even though I have changed the setting for the ***maximum evaluation***?
Please give your feedback.

Comment: Is the fundamental issue really convergence of the optimization, i.e would even 5000 evaluations be enough?

Comment: Yes, it is true, maybe not enough, but what I want to ask is this:
Why is there still a 3000 evaluation limit, even though I raised the evaluation limit using the options?
For example, if I set up this number at 5000, 10000, 20000, the solver stops with 3000 evaluations again. Regardless of the options, this is the result:

Solver stopped prematurely.
fmincon stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 3.000000e + 03.

Comment: Try passing `options` to `fmincon`

Comment: So do you mean that options do not pass to fmincon when I use as follows?
`options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'MaxFunctionEvaluations',20000,'Algorithm','active-set','Display','iter');
[x,fval] = fmincon(problem);`

Comment: When I try to send the options to the function as `[x, fval] = fmincon (problem,options);` an error occurs because there is no x0 (initial values for variables) and A. I think when we want to pass options like this, we should use it in the form: `[x, fval] = fmincon (x0, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub, opts)`. But I have defined **problem** before and why do I have to define matrices like A and b again? Why doesn't it work like `[x, fval] = fmincon (problem,options);`?